# Showing continuity of a linear transformation using Closed graph theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, closed-graph

Let $T$ be a linear transformation of a Banach space $B$ into a Banach Space $B'$. Let $E \subset B^{'*} $ satisfying -

**A)** $E$ separates points of $B'$ (i.e. for for $x , y \in B' , x \neq y$ there
is some $\phi \in E$ such that $\phi (x) \neq \phi(y)$) .

**B)** For every $\phi \in E$, $\phi \circ T$ is continuous.

I need to show that $T$ is continuous.

Now I suppose I need to use the **Closed Graph theorem** here but I am not getting any clue as to where to go with it.

Comment: Could you add your thoughts on the problem? Why do you think the closed graph theorem should be used?

Comment: To be frank, I have read open map theorem and closed graph theorem so far and the latter seems to make more sense as it explicitly deals with Continuity of linear maps. I know you asked for my mathematical thoughts but so far I have nothing but intuition..